# Why is getWindow() not able to be resolved?

Tags: java, javascript, java-7, jsobject

I can't resolve the getWindow(); method for some reason...

```
import java.applet.Applet;

import netscape.javascript.JSObject;

public class Class466 {
public static void method6020(Applet applet, String string, int i)
        throws Throwable {
    try {
        JSObject.getWindow(applet).eval(string);
    } catch (RuntimeException runtimeexception) {
        throw Class346.method4175(runtimeexception, new StringBuilder()
                .append("tf.a(").append(')').toString());
    }
}

public static Object method6021(Applet applet, String string, short i)
        throws Throwable {
    try {
        return JSObject.getWindow(applet).call(string, null);
    } catch (RuntimeException runtimeexception) {
        throw Class346.method4175(runtimeexception, new StringBuilder()
                .append("tf.f(").append(')').toString());
    }
}

public static Object method6022(Applet applet, String string,
        Object[] objects, byte i) throws Throwable {
    try {
        return JSObject.getWindow(applet).call(string, objects);
    } catch (RuntimeException runtimeexception) {
        throw Class346.method4175(runtimeexception, new StringBuilder()
                .append("tf.b(").append(')').toString());
    }
}

Class466() throws Throwable {
    throw new Error();
}
}
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

In `jdk1.7.0_11`, I noticed that there are two separate jars within

```
../jre/lib/
```

that contain the `netscape.javascript.JSObject.class`, namely

- jfxrt.jar
- plugin.jar

In the case of my IDE (IntelliJ), when I created a project SDK for Java it added both the `jfxrt.jar` and the `plugin.jar` jars to the classpath.

As the `jfxrt.jar` appears alphabetically before `plugin.jar` in the **classpath**, my application code was not resolving

```
JSObject.getWindow(...)
```

properly.

As we're not using JavaFX within our application I simply removed the jfxrt.jar from my projects Java SDK classpath.

Comment: Related issue tracker link: [RT-37103: Not able to resolve JSObject.getWindow(this) in a java applet project](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-37103).

Comment: I have fixed the very same issue by reordering Java SDK lib dependency. On IntelliJ, I opened Project Structure->Modules->Dependencies and then moved java's lib down at the bottom.

Comment: Interesting how this also seems to be the case using OpenJDK 8's `javac`. it seems to include the `lib/ext` jars to the class path by default, even though I only specify `-cp plugins.jar` in my command line. I had to actually remove/rename the `jfxrt.jar` to be able to compile it.

Answer (score 0):

Is the "MAYSCRIPT" applet tag parameter declared ?

```
<APPLET code="XYZApp.class" codebase="html/" align="baseline"
 width="200" height="200" MAYSCRIPT>
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure where I would need to declare that to be honest with you!

Comment: JSObject is for Java to Javascript communication (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/plugin/developer_guide/java_js.html). So youd should have an applet in your html page no?

Comment: It's a standalone application :p

Comment: *"It's a standalone application"* LOL!  What on Earth 'Window' do you think that would return?  The `JSObject` only gets created in an applet environment (e.g. a browser).

Comment: Basically, It's a client for a java based browser game, it launchs the jar from the website inside my client but never actually opens a physical page

Comment: Then it seems your stuffed unless you can figure out what a JRE in a browser does to establish/initialize the `JSObject`.  But then, what is the point of any of this?  It is hard to tell what you are trying to achieve with names like `Class346.method4175`.

Comment: Basically it's for a game and that is "sort of" browser based, the actual jar is pulled off a website and then loaded into my application within a jframe, this class is used to evaluate the strings (the game chat)

Comment: Also, sorry for the poor naming conventions :P

Answer (score -2):

I think you have to add:

```
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent
```

Comment: :P If I import them thy are unused imports.

Comment: Totally incorrect answer, not even close to being correct.